# Do hydrocollator packs help treat a tendinosis?

Tags: tendinopathy

I am reading some medical records and saw this prescription for physical therapy given by an orthopedics physician:

[image]

Looking at other part of the record, what they call "tendinitis" is a tendinosis.

Do hydrocollator packs help treat a tendinosis?